# Not able to launch emulator in Android Studio (trying flutter for the first time)

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-emulator

I go to tools -> AVD manager and click on the Run icon. I see starting AVD at the bottom, but emulator does not launch. If I try to run for the second time i get a popup error "AVD .... is already running, If that is not the case, delete the file..."

[image: screenshot]

I delete the file and try again and the whole process repeats. thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the Stackoverflow. Can you try another OS Image, maybe Android Nougat. Also try to restart your computer.

Comment: Depending on your hardware you might also need to wait a bit for first start.